# appending to a list with dynamic names

Tags: r, list, append, names

I have a list in R:

```
a <- list(n1 = "hi", n2 = "hello")
```

I would like to append to this *named* list but the names must be dynamic.  That is, they are created from a string (for example: `paste("another","name",sep="_")`

I tried doing this, which does not work:

```
c(a, parse(text="paste(\"another\",\"name\",sep=\"_\")=\"hola\"")
```

What is the correct way to do this?  The end goal is just to append to this list and choose my names dynamically.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could just use indexing with double brackets.  Either of the following methods should work.

```
a <- list(n1 = "hi", n2 = "hello")
val <- "another name"
a[[val]] <- "hola"
a
#$n1
#[1] "hi"
#
#$n2
#[1] "hello"
#
#$`another name`
#[1] "hola"

 a[[paste("blah", "ok", sep = "_")]] <- "hey"
 a
#$n1
#[1] "hi"
#
#$n2
#[1] "hello"
#
#$`another name`
#[1] "hola"
#
#$blah_ok
#[1] "hey"
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `setNames` to set the names on the fly:

```
a <- list(n1 = "hi", n2 = "hello")
c(a,setNames(list("hola"),paste("another","name",sep="_")))
```

Result:

```
$n1
[1] "hi"

$n2
[1] "hello"

$another_name
[1] "hola"
```